# Lowest possible memory footprint for a local HTML page (with JS)

Tags: javascript, html, command-line, popup, microsoft-edge

I am trying to build an ultra-lightweight media player.
[See what I am basing it on here](https://github.com/Noah-Jaffe/Mixcloud_player/blob/main/MUSICPLAYER2.html). This repo uses a fairly low overhead Microsoft Edge window to display the webpage.

I am wondering if is there a simpler approach. Are there any [additional startup flags for Microsoft Edge to get an even lower footprint?](https://github.com/Noah-Jaffe/Mixcloud_player/blob/main/START%20MUSIC.bat) The goal is to not download anything else and use pure js for this.

Assumptions:

- OS: Windows 10
- Applications available: chrome, firefox, edge, or something else you recommend?

Comment: Maybe chromium has a lower footprint? Since it doesn't have all the extra microsoft fluff added? The flags should mostly be the same. Or else you can try node-webkit: https://nwjs.io

Comment: You can also add `--disable-extensions` to avoid some extensions loading in InPrivate mode. Besides, maybe app mode is more suitable for your situation and uses fewer memory? you can try `--app=./MUSICPLAYER.html`.